# How to run test by testcase directly with common structure

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

```
app
   template
   static
   tests
      __init__.py
      auth_test.py
   __init__.py
app.db
config.py
manager.py
env
```

This is my simple structure and I can test it using manager.py. I didn't get good performance, so I am looking for a better way. Some people said to use the flaskr extension, but there is a problem with the installation process.

I think if I can get the code below to work, I will see a performance increase.

```
import unittest
from app import app


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()
        db.create_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

when I run

```
python auth_test.py
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named app
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this error because your `tests` folder in the `app` folder. Just put the two folders along and launch the `tests` module from the root.

For tests with Flask, I use this [guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/) and this [example](https://github.com/kelsmj/flask-test-example) :)

See ya !

Comment: After tests folder is moved to root directory, I can't still work it.

Comment: Can you tell me more detail? I can't work it out even after to read what you recommend me documents